# React Native Agora Sdk

Tags: react-native, sdk, communication, live-streaming, agora.io

I am using [Agora Sdk](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/landing-page?platform=React%20Native) for calls and live streaming it is possible to call from agora to Sim Card Number or any other SDK platform which is used for calls to sim in react native. I Search many sites but no result can anyone help me plz.

Answer (score 0):

Agora doesn't offer support for VoIP at the moment, so you can't call to Sim cards.